# Will pulling and pushing to a git Repo with different histories affect pull requests if the Heads are the same?

Tags: git, github

I have a forked upstream repo that I pulled from twice and a commit that I merged into my origin and was merged into upstream(not my repo) via a pull request. Now `git status` is

> Your branch and 'upstream/master' have diverged, and have 3 and 31
>   different commits each, respectively.

When I run git pull a new merge commit is created because my commit is not detected as the same as the pull requested commit merged into upstream.

**If I create a merge commit locally through pull, will those 3 commits that I'm ahead by affect future pull requests now that they are in my history but not the upstream history?**

Also, I wonder why the first merge before my local commit is now listed as a commit ahead of upstream when I was merging from upstream?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I create a merge commit locally through pull, will those 3 commits that I'm ahead by affect future pull requests now that they are in my history but not the upstream history?

The typical next step you would take, after doing a `git pull` which creates a merge commit, would be to `git push` your local branch to the remote.  This would incorporate the unique work from the 3 commits you made since the remote and local branches diverged.  So the usual workflow here is that you would bring your work into the remote branch somehow.

To better understand the `git status` message you saw, consider the following diagram:

```
remote: ... A -- B -- C ... (29 other commits)
             \
local:        M -- N -- O
```

In other words, both your local and remote branches branched from the `A` commit.  And since then, there have been 31 commits made to the remote branch, while you made 3 commits of your own.

Comment: Ok, I did something wrong. Should merge commits from that top graph be listed as ahead on my local from upstream?

Comment: No, commits from the top graph are what others (possibly including yourself) have committed since the last time you synched with the remote branch.  When you merge, you bring in the functionality of commits `B`, `C`, ..., into your local branch, in the form of a merge commit.

Comment: Alright, not sure why 2 merge commits from upstream are commits "ahead" of upstream.

Comment: @user5389726598465 "Ahead" refers to the position of each branch relative to the commit at which they both diverged.  Get it?  Both you and the remote branch are "ahead" of where you split.

Comment: Since I'm pulling and pushing from/to different repos, I will always be progressively more diverged (ahead by commits) from the upstream then since I never merge back into it? Is there a recommended way to fix that beside ignoring it or force overwriting my master with the upstream?

Comment: The only real way to prevent this is to make sure you stay up to date.  If your code diverges too much, it can lead to problems.

Comment: But even if I stay up to date, the repo is still going to say I'm ahead after I merge because I never push a merge to upstream. I push the merge back to origin. Or maybe I still need to investigate those merges more closely that are "ahead" because I did something wrong.

Comment: Hmmm...forks aren't an area that I am an expert in.  I can't comment further.

Comment: Ok, I'll look into those merges and ask a new q if there's something fishy.

Answer (score 0):

Since my upstream branch is set up like this in .git:

```
[remote "upstream"]
    url = https://github.com/Othersrepo.git
    pushurl = https://github.com/myRepo.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/upstream/*
```

the "ahead" refers to differences between local and myRepo, not the Othersrepo so git status doesn't show whether I'm ahead of the Othersrepo that I pulled from.

Run `git push` and I'm up to date. 
Run `git fetch` and I'm behind by x commits again.